# How can I map a nested object effectively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested object which looks like this:

```
const notes = {
    infantry: {
        mainHand: {
            '3OayPUASk1JJFJwpKW7u': {
                id: '3OayPUASk1JJFJwpKW7u',
                note: 'Champion blade is overall less powerful ... ',
            },
            '5N3y7DfjZwFTPxoyg3La': {
                id: '5N3y7DfjZwFTPxoyg3La',
                note: 'Ghastly Cane has really good stats, ...',
            },
            '7mOdjVqp9co87Ymkvk9F': {
                id: '7mOdjVqp9co87Ymkvk9F',
                note: 'Terror Lash is a decent piece, but...',
            },
        },
        offHand: {
            G6qQaEqzWcMytMI3W7re: {
                id: 'G6qQaEqzWcMytMI3W7re',
                note: 'Ranged ATK Jewel',
            },
        },
    },
    ranged: {
        '7mOdjVqp9co87gmkvk9F': {
            id: '7mOdjVqp9co87gmkvk9F',
            note: 'Frostwing sword makes a great starter piece for Inf set..',
        },
    },
};
```

and I use the Notes component like this (to access the infantry prop):

```
 
function Notes(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {Object.values(notes.infantry[props.type]).map((item) => (
                <div key={item.id}>
                    <h5>{item.note}</h5>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

and I call the component like this:

```
  <Notes type={'mainHand'} />
```

The issue here is, I don't know how to reuse the component to dynamically change `infantry` to `ranged`.

I tried to change it to :

```
  {Object.values(notes[props.type]).map((item) => (
                    <div className='p-3 col-sm' key={item.id}>
                        <h5>{item.note}</h5>
                    </div>
```

and pass  `<Notes type={'[infantry[mainHand]]'} />` but it's not working.

The only way I can solve the issue is to make a Notes component for every `notes` property (infantry,ranged etc)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a presentation/container component pattern and make your Notes component as simple as possible. Extract data retrieval logic to some upstream container. For example:

```
function Notes({ items }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {items.map(({ id, note }) => (
                <div key={id}>
                    <h5>{note}</h5>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
<Notes items={Object.values(notes.infantry.mainHand)} />
```

or if you want to encapsulate notes data inside `Notes` component you can pass the selector function as follows:

```
function Notes({ selector }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {selector(notes).map(({ id, note }) => (
                <div key={id}>
                    <h5>{note}</h5>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

...

<Notes selector={notes => Object.values(notes.infantry.mainHand)} />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I might miss something, but at your first solution, you used map on the object? I get a "items.map is not a function" error.

Comment: Sorry. Ive edited my answer to be consistent with your original data structure